# Servlet contents missing

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

[image showing login page not getting contents of the included servlet Classnames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZpm1.jpg)
[image showing login page before form processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKUV8.jpg)
i am trying to forward a request from a servlet to a jsp page, that jsp page has one or more included servlets in the page, actually forwarding the request to the page from the servlet is not my issue, but when it takes me to that page, the contents of the included servlet(s) in that page is missing...
here is the source code... for the class to be included in the page

```
package Classes;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "Classnames", urlPatterns = {"/Classnames"})
public class Classnames extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{
            Connection conn= ConnectionPackage.MyConnection.getConnection();
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                PreparedStatement ps;
                ResultSet rs;
                String class_name;
                int class_id;
                ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT class.class_name,class.id FROM class WHERE 1");
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                    class_name = rs.getString("class_name");
                    class_id = rs.getInt("id");
                    out.println("<option value="+class_id+">"+class_name+"</option>");
                }
                ps.close();
                rs.close();
                conn.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

then the page containing the included servlet is below

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="David Tega">
        <meta name="description" content="Cbt Training Platform">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsiveness.css">
        <meta name="copyright" content="copyright 2005-2020 Tech Giants"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Brainfield School Platform</title>
    </head>
    <body id="login" style="background-image: url('images/headway-5QgIuuBxKwM-unsplash.jpg'); background-size: cover;" >
        <div class="w3-padding-large w3-white">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <p class="w3-wide w3-text-brown w3-large">Login...</p>
                <p class="w3-text-red w3-small">${loginErrorMessage}</p>
            </div>
            <form action="StudentLogin" method="POST">
                    <div class="w3-row-padding">
                        <div class="w3-half container">
                            <select class="w3-select w3-border" name="class_name">
                                <option disabled selected>Class</option>
                                <jsp:include page="Classnames" flush="true"></jsp:include>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-half container">
                            <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="student_rollno" type="text" placeholder="(XXX)" maxlength="3">
                        </div>
                        <button class="w3-button w3-col w3-margin-top w3-gray w3-border w3-padding-small w3-text-white">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally the servlet that process the form on the StudentLogin page is below

```
package LoginPackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(name = "StudentLogin", urlPatterns = {"/StudentLogin"})
public class StudentLogin extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{
            Connection conn= ConnectionPackage.MyConnection.getConnection();
                int roleId =6,state=1;
                PreparedStatement ps;
                ResultSet rs;
                HttpSession ss = request.getSession(true);
                String classId = request.getParameter("class_name");
                String rollno = request.getParameter("student_rollno"),role,name,picture;
                String id;
                ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT students.userId,user.full_name,user.picture,roleinfo.name FROM students INNER JOIN user ON (students.userId = user.id) INNER JOIN roleinfo ON (user.roleId = roleinfo.id) WHERE students.rollno = '"+rollno+"' AND students.classId ='"+classId+"' AND user.roleId ="+roleId+" AND user.state = "+state+" ");
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    role = rs.getString("name");
                    name = rs.getString("full_name");
                    picture = rs.getString("picture");
                    id = rs.getString("userId");
                    ss.setAttribute("full_name", name);
                    ss.setAttribute("user_role", role);
                    ss.setAttribute("user_picture", picture);
                    ss.setAttribute("userId", id);
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+ "/StudentProfile.jsp" );
                }else{
                    request.setAttribute("loginErrorMessage", "Incorrect Details, Try Again");
                    RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("StudentLogin.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure `conn` is not null on the Servlet? The included resource cannot do a redirect

Comment: @areus, yeah i just checked ran my connection class and its ok, and thanks for the tip, i always wondered why it never redirects to my index page not until now. so what do you advise i put instead if conn is null and not to forget it still a'int working

Comment: Could you try `<jsp:include page="/Classnames" flush="true" />` . I mean, using a leading `/` in the page, and using and empty tag `<jsp:include />` instead of opening and ending `<jsp:include></jsp:include>`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: And what's the result if you call `/Classnames` directly from the browser?

Comment: I get this : <option value="4">Primary 1</option> etc

Comment: Your code seems correct. What's the html result of the JSP?

Comment: Before forwarding, the page shows the drop down, but after forwarding it doesn't show anything

Comment: Hey, i got something, if i tried using a doGet() method, it shows the included class, though it is not what i want... is there anything you can spot that am not seeing? thanks

Comment: Not sure i'm following you. You should consider to indicate the name of each file in your question, especially for the JSP, and publish the resulting html of the failing call

Comment: @areus i added an image already, please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first access the login JSP page you do it with a GET method. The JSP processes the `<jsp:include />` calling the doGet method of the Classnames servlet.

When you submit the form, using the POST method, on your StudentLogin servlet you are using a `RequestDispatcher.forward`, so the login JSP page processess the POST request, and the `<jsp:include />` calls the doPost method of the Classnames servlet.

You should refactor your Classnames servlet, to output the same results with either a doGet or a doPost, or you could use a POST-redirect-GET (and convert the `loginErrorMessage` request attribute to a request param)

To refactor your Classnames servlet, you could put your current doGet method implementation in a new method like:

```
protected void outputOptions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

And call that method form the `doGet` and `doPost`.

Or you could simply override the `service` method of the HttpSevlet class. The `service` method, as stated in javadoc:

> Receives standard HTTP requests from the public service method and dispatches them to the doXXX methods defined in this class

So, putting your logic in that method you could omit overriding doGet and doPost methods, as the `service` method would be invoked in any case:

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
        Connection conn= ConnectionPackage.MyConnection.getConnection();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;
        String class_name;
        int class_id;
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT class.class_name,class.id FROM class WHERE 1");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            class_name = rs.getString("class_name");
            class_id = rs.getInt("id");
            out.println("<option value="+class_id+">"+class_name+"</option>");
        }
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        // normally you should'nt ignore exceptions silently 
        log("Error getting options", ex);
    }
}
```

The only downfall of this option is that the `service` method will be called for all HTTP methods, not just only GET and POST. But at is in an included servlet, that's not really a problem.

Comment: for the first option you mean i should call the doGet() method in the doPost() method, and for the second option you mean i should do something like this in the doPost() method: response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+ "/StudentLogin.jsp?errrorMessage='Incorrect Details'" );

Comment: Yes. You could also add an utility method and call it from both doGet or doPost, or simply override the servlet `service` method.

Comment: Please can you throw more lights on what you said now, with an example ...thanks